# How to create a date using the current year, in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Can someone tell me how I can use the current year instead of hard-coding the year in the below line?

```
$yearCurrent = date('Y');
$dayLast = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
```

I guess this is probably something very simple but I couldn't find a solution for this so far.

Comment: There's a lot of ways of doing this. Where is the non-year part of the date coming from?

Comment: You tried this ? `$dayLast = new DateTime($yearCurrent.'-12-31');`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is highly localised to a single use-case. (Pleased you fixed it, though!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last day of the year will always be 12-31 so try:

```
$dayLast = new DateTime($yearCurrent.'-12-31');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I will accept as soon as I can !

Answer (score 5):

why not just use:

```
$dayLast = $yearCurrent."-12-31";?
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, more compactly:

```
$dayLast = new DateTime(date('Y').'-12-31');
```

Unless you need the variable set to current year for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation, which will always give a date for the current year:-

```
$dayLast = \DateTime::createFromFormat('-m-d', '-12-31')->format('Y-m-d');
```

This does not require your `$yearCurrent` variable.

See the [DateTime manual](http://php.net/datetime).